# angular error in the httpRequest response

Tags: typescript, rxjs, httprequest, angular-cli

I'm trying to make a request for the microsoft graph api and get the user's profile photo, I'm using "angularCLI" I've tried everything else, there is still a response error.

I tried using python and only in angular I have this error.

```
  getUserProfilePhoto(token: string): any{

   const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token, responseType: 'text' as 'json',
        'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',})
    };
   return this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT + '/photo/$value', httpOptions).toPromise();
  }
```

Erro

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:17352:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:412:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:45445:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:411:40) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:180:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:493:38) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1634:18) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1671:25)
text: "����JFIF``��C"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: Don't set your content-type on a `GET` request. It doesn't have a body. Also, `responseType: 'text' as 'json'` is nonsensical. You want `accept: 'application/json'` if anything.

Comment: why this `responseType: 'text' as 'json'` ?